# how to insert byte array in database?

Tags: java, android

I have problem about inserting byte[] of android database.
I have two class called DB.java and DBAdapter.java as below.
I get the following error. "Error insert image=[B@43d1b7b8"
Basically, i followed on some tut, but still can't work. Hope someone can help.

#### DB.java:

```
public class DB extends Activity{
    private final String imageInSD = "/sdcard/e5.jpg";
    Bitmap bitmap;
    byte[] buf =null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos );
        buf = bos.toByteArray(); 
     
    db.open();        
    long id;
    id = db.insertTitle(buf);        
    db.close();
    
    System.out.println("ID:"+id);
            
}
```

}

#### DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";    
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "books";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "photo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table photo (image blob not null);";
        
    private final Context context; 
    
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
        
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    
    
    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    

    public long insertTitle(byte[] buf) 
    {   
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, buf);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wiil suggest you to  save your image file on sdcard and save its path in database.

Comment: What kind of answer is this??